# Get Max Speed Limit of a road segment or streets Android

Tags: android, performance, api, gps, geolocation

Is there any api or web service which i can use to get the max speed limit of my current location from android device i.e. when my gps location (long lat) point to any road segment or street. Please guide me how to implement this functionality in my android code.

Want to create an app which alerts when one is over speeding. I got the my current speed, but no max speed to match with.

Comment: http://data.gov.uk/forum/general-discussion/road-speed-data-location-latitudelongitude

Comment: i would like to know how to implement them in my android code.

Comment: This site is not for asking people how to do something as a whole. Learn it, try it, and if you run into specific problems then come back and ask about those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many open source API's and paid which can be used for this purpose.

**Paid:**
 Tomtom is a good example as its a huge and very wide API for many other tasks as navigation over their own offline maps.

**Free:**
[Wikispeedia](http://www.wikispeedia.org/) is good but they require speed-limits in return as favor for them, or otherwise the access to the database is very limited. The most popular way to find the speed limit is to send lat, lon like this:

```
http://www.wikispeedia.org/speedlimit/geo4a.php?name=ALL&latlng=35.17545,-89.53372
```

Alternate to wikispeedia is [OSM (Open Street Map)](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) this is what i am using and works great for me as it returns you hell of information. Use it like this and you will get every information:

```
http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[maxspeed=*][bbox=72.998251,33.670049,72.998451,33.670249]
```

You can also use its wiki for more tags.

Comment: The XAPI variant `http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?` is only provided via a compatibility layer and involves additional (unnecessary) overhead. Please migrate to [Overpass QL](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL) instead.

Comment: Hi Salman.., how to set the boundary in bbox..plz help